# Why is there a large space between footnote number and footnote text?

Tags: footnotes

The following two lines of code produce the following two outputs, which are screen shots of the bottom of the PDF output. Why is there a large gap when I justify the text, and how do I get rid of it please?

```
\footnote{\normalsize \justify{Read this equation as: change in population in the next time period is the population in the current time period times the growth rate.}}

\footnote{\normalsize {Read this equation as: change in population in the next time
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: From where you got `\justify`? Why do you need it?

Comment: apart from removing `\justify` (which always adds vertical space) you should probably remove  `\normalsize` it is rather rare to have a size command there, the size of footnotes can be set up as a global default, you shouldn't need to change the size on each one,

Answer (score 1):

`\justify` (which you should almost never need, justification is the default) is not intended to be used as a command it is the implemntaion of `\begin{justify}` like `\center` which is the internal version of `\begin{center}` and is a display environment that sets the content off with vertical space.  (Presumably, although you did not say, you are using the `ragged2e` package which defines the `justify` environment)